# C# plugin architecture in Web API

Tags: c#, architecture, mef

I have a web application that uses Web Api. The application provides the ability to send marketing campaigns via popular services such as Mailjet, Mailchimp etc. For the plugin architecture I use MEF from .NET. The problem is that when I develop a new plugin for another service I need to restart the application to load a new plugin. Is it is possible and how to implement plugin which can be loaded at runtime without need to restart the app?

Comment: What is a plugin? A `*dll` implementing specific interfaces?

Comment: Yes. I use MEF for this purpose and plugins are *.dll's which are loaded on runtime with MEF by scanning specific folders.

Comment: It's ok. I found solution: http://multithreadthoughts.blogspot.com/2013/08/mef-and-appdomain-remove-assemblies-on.html